# Encriptar parametro de una url en laravel

Tags: laravel, url

Necesito encriptar un parametro en una url por ejemplo http://localhost/blog/public/ficha/ver/1 y mostrarlo de esta forma http://localhost/blog/public/ficha/ver/SDAS9238J2

esta es la vista 
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La primera vista donde cargas el formulario, la llamas directamente desde la ruta, o desde un `controller` ?

Comment: la llamo desde la ruta

Comment: Si no necesitas mucha seguridad al encriptarlo puedes usar el paquete Hashids

Comment: podrías poner como tienes la ruta en el archivo `web` me refiero a la que usas para mostrar el formulario.

Comment: Route::get('/ficha/editar/{id}', 'fichaController@editarficha');

Comment: Me refiero a la ruta donde llamas la vista que pones en tu pregunta, no a donde mandas el formulario.

Comment: No se cual es tu idea, pero usé éste paquete en varios proyectos y funciona muy bien: [Laravel FakeID](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-FakeId/). Se supone que es más rápido que Hashids.

Comment: Existe un paquete llamado FakeID, hace todo el trabajo por ti.

Answer (score 3):

Lo único que te falta es poner:

```
encrypt($var->id)
```

Una vez estas en el controlador de la ruta, haces:
 `decrypt("tu variable id")` y ya está.

Comment: this really works. Thanks!